# Azure OMS browser usage stats monthly

Tags: azure, oms

Apologies upfront if this is a silly question, just started with using Azure OMS. We’d like to have a monthly report to show browser usage on our site.

Is there a quick way to configure this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be use application insights for this, not OMS (although you can push the app insights data into OMS if you wish).App insights has analytics information, such as browser data.